# How to take remote data access (from stock market) and combine them into a single dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, join

I tried grabbing data from morningstar and combining different stock, but I can't figure out how to combine the data properly. I want to organize it by Date, but it just stacks the data on top of each other.

```
print('test')
print('testing')
#this program will read data from morningstar and interpret them using pandas

import pandas as pd
import datetime

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like

import pandas_datareader.data as web

start = datetime.datetime(2010,1,1) #datetime is (year, month, day)
end = datetime.date.today()

#Getting data from morningstar
microsoft = pd.DataFrame(web.DataReader("MSFT", "morningstar", start, end))
apple = pd.DataFrame(web.DataReader("AAPL","morningstar", start, end))
google = pd.DataFrame(web.DataReader("GOOG", "morningstar", start, end))


stocks = pd.DataFrame({"MSFT": microsoft["Volume"],
                   "AAPL": apple["Volume"],
                  "GOOG": google["Volume"]})


print(stocks)
```

Basically I want the data to look like this:

```
          stock1          stock2        stock3

date1       123            345           234

date2       657            294           553

date3       786            321           933
```

But instead it turns out like this:

```
           stock1         stock2        stock3

date1       123            NaN           NaN

date2       657            NaN           NaN

date3       786            NaN           NaN

date1       NaN            345           NaN

date2       NaN            294           NaN

date3       NaN            321           NaN

date1       NaN            NaN           234

date2       NaN            NaN           553

date3       NaN            NaN           933
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `reset_index` at the end when you create your new dataframe

```
stocks = pd.DataFrame({"MSFT": microsoft["Volume"].reset_index(level=0,drop=True),
                   "AAPL": apple["Volume"].reset_index(level=0,drop=True),
                  "GOOG": google["Volume"].reset_index(level=0,drop=True)})
```

Comment: I think that did it. Thanks!!